# App Foreground callback coming late in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, application-lifecycle

I am developing an SDK in swift for IOS apps. The sdk basically posts events data to server. I need to know whether app is in background or foreground. I used the notification center observer to get callbacks in the applicationDidBecomeActice and applicationWillEnterForeground callbacks. But I found the callbacks to be coming late i.e the callback is coming as late as when viewDidLoad of splash screen is getting called. I have also worked with ProcessLifecycleOwner in Android where the callback is triggered instantly.

Can someone please tell me if this is the ideal behavior in ios. If yes, what else can be done to know when the app comes to foreground instantly

P.S - This is my first question on S O., apologies for long question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what late is? That the `applicationDidBecomeActive` comes after the `viewDidLoad` isn't strange. You could check whether or not the `applicationDidBecomeActive` comes before the `viewDidAppear` function. Before a view is rendered (appears) to the screen, it must be loaded. I'm not sure how the app lifecycle and the view lifecycle interact, but it doesn't seem weird to me that the `viewDidLoad` comes first

Comment: I may be wrong as I am new to IOS, but on drawing analogy with Android, I believe first application creation callback should come before we start to get callbacks of viewDidLoad. Since in android, first application is created and then activities are made

Comment: Yeah well iOS and Android are two very different systems and you should expect the behavior to be different. So coming to your second question: yes, this is how iOS lifecycle notifications work. Maybe looking at the naming more closely will help explain: "application *did* become active". This is the closest you can get to knowing that the app is now active.